# VeraCrypt - Permanently decrypt... - Error: VeraCrypt can in-place encrypt only a partition, a dynamic volume, or an entire system drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption, veracrypt

I have a `WD Red Plus NAS WD140EFFX - 14 TB - 3,5"` drive that is encrypted with VeraCrypt AES(Twofish). It is not the system drive. I can mount the drive without a problem and the drive shows no error when checking it.

[image]

If I use VeraCrypt, select the volume and then use `Volume Tools...` and select `Permanently decrypt...`

[image]

I get these messages:

[image]

[image]

> VeraCrypt Volume Creation Wizard
>
> Error: VeraCrypt can in-place encrypt only a partition, a dynamic
> volume, or an entire system drive. Please make sure the specified path
> is valid.

[image]

I use latest VeraCrypt 1.26.7 but I have also tried with VeraCrypt 1.25.9 and older VeraCrypt 1.24. Same error in every version.

https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html

I have looked at other forum posts with the same error but no one seems to have a fix.

https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/f4f9c50e6c/

https://www.reddit.com/r/VeraCrypt/comments/csod02/issue_with_decrypting_whole_drive/

I have tried to decrypt with the drive mounted and dismounted, same error.

Since I can access the files I know they can be transferred to another drive but I would just like to decrypt it without having to move 12TB of data.

https://veracrypt.eu/en/Removing%20Encryption.html

Comment: Did you see this one : https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/a0bfc76212/ - It's about container.

Comment: I fear you'll have to move 12TB of data ...